# Creating a User With cognito User Pool in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use the cognito user pool js sdk to create a user in cognito user pool. I was able to successfully do so on the front end by following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html). However, I wanted to do it in the backend with node. I am trying to include the sdk like this

```
const AWSCognito = require('./amazon-cognito-identity.min.js');
const `AWSCognitoSDK` = require('./aws-cognito-sdk.min.js');
```

But node of the stuff I am using is defined. For example `AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';` doesnt work because AWSCognito doesnt seem to have the attribute config.region. I tryed it with `AWSCognitoSDK` but that comes as an empty object when I log it to the console, so I wasn't really expecting that to work anyways. I tried using the solution in the below answer, but I couldn't get it to work
[AWS Cognito unauthenticated login error (window is not defined) [JS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219518/aws-cognito-unauthenticated-login-error-window-is-not-defined-js)

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me in including the sdk and getting these lines to work in node

```
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '...', // your user pool id here
    ClientId : '...' // your app client id here
};
var userPool = 
new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Note: I also tried installing amazon-cognito-identity-js through npm but faced the same issues

**---UPDATE---**

I did the npm install based on Patrick's answer. Here is the errror I get

```
    let userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
                                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'CognitoUserPool' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bbhakhrani/projects/nodekb/app.js:19:62)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
```

When I console.log this AWSCognito object, `const AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');`, here are the properties that show

```
    { __esModule: true,
  AuthenticationDetails: [Getter],
  AuthenticationHelper: [Getter],
  CognitoAccessToken: [Getter],
  CognitoIdToken: [Getter],
  CognitoRefreshToken: [Getter],
  CognitoUser: [Getter],
  CognitoUserAttribute: [Getter],
  CognitoUserPool: [Getter],
  CognitoUserSession: [Getter],
  CookieStorage: [Getter],
  DateHelper: [Getter] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the *amazon-cognito-identity-js* module using the Node.js package manager (npm) by executing this command in your project's root directory:

```
npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

This will put the module in a special directory named *node_modules*.

You can then use *require* in your code without specifying a path, just the npm package name suffices, Node.js will automatically resolve the path:

```
const AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work. I updated the post with the error I get when doing it this way as well. Please check the post for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get that line to work. I just changed it to  `new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData)` instead of `new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData)`, and it worked.