# Cognito UnknownError after turn on device registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, srp-protocol

As per requirement, I need to turn on device registration to `Always`. However, our SRP flow starts failing with the below issue.

```
{ code: 'UnknownError', message: 'Unknown error, the response body from fetch is: undefined' }
```

After doing some research, I found one similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219518/aws-cognito-unauthenticated-login-error-window-is-not-defined-js), but it seems like the only solution is to turn device registration off.

It's failing while running `node get-token.js` script to retrieve token for our CI/CD testing pipeline.

```
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authCfg, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log("Result : ", result);
            const token = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            resolve(token)
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            console.error("Failure : ", err);
            console.log(new Error().stack);
            reject(new Error("An error occurred: " + err))
        },
        newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
            cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(p, userAttributes, this);
        },
    });
```

Comment: You're problem is resolved or not ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I missed the point mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219518/aws-cognito-unauthenticated-login-error-window-is-not-defined-js) . Adding the below code works.

```
const WindowMock = require('window-mock');
global.window = {localStorage: WindowMock.localStorage};
global.navigator = () => null;
```