# AWS Amplify with Nuxt.js - Reference Error: Navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use Nuxt.js with AWS Amplify for SSR/SEO benefits.

I'm able to get Amplify added to my project and have successfully configured Amplify using the "Manual Configuration" steps described in the Amplify Docs. I was even able to get basic SignUp, SignIn methods working.

However, after refreshing the app I receive the below error. I believe this is because of the SSR aspect of Nuxt as referenced in this [old Stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219518/aws-cognito-unauthenticated-login-error-window-is-not-defined-js).

The thread above mentions adding this line:

```
global.navigator = () => null;
```

However I have no idea where to add this.

Error Details:

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

File: node_modules/@aws-amplify/analytics/dist/aws-amplify-analytics.js

Place in the code, (line 38103):

```
var logger = new _aws_amplify_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ConsoleLogger"]('AWSPinpointProvider');
var RETRYABLE_CODES = [429, 500];
var ACCEPTED_CODES = [202];
var MOBILE_SERVICE_NAME = 'mobiletargeting';
var BEACON_SUPPORTED = navigator && typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function'; // events buffer

var BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
var FLUSH_SIZE = 100;
var FLUSH_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000; // 5s
```

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute only on client side wrap it in

```
if(process.server){
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Doing the opposite of what you wrote actually worked. Looks like I'm probably good to go here!